# Copy a chunk of one tensor into another one in C++ API

Tags: c++, pytorch, libtorch

I need to copy a row of one tensor (in `c++ API`) into some part of another tensor, form which the begin and end indexes are available. Within C++ we can use something like:

```cpp
int myints[] = {10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70};
std::vector<int> myvector(18);

std::copy(myints, myints + 3, myvector.begin() + 4);
```

to copy three values from `myints` into `myvector`, starting at the fourth index. 
I was wondering if there is a similar API in `libtorch` (i.e., C++)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The C++ API provides the **Python** *slice equivalent* function

```
at::Tensor at::Tensor::slice(int64_t dim, int64_t start, int64_t end, int64_t step);
```

You can thus do something like:

```
auto myints = torch::Tensor({10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70});
auto myvector = torch::ones({18});

myvector.slice(0, 3, 7) = myints.slice(0, 0, 3);
```

in your case using `dim=0` first dimension

Comment: `auto myints = torch::Tensor({10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70});` fails on VS2019 with C2440: '<function-style-cast>': cannot convert from 'initializer list' to 'at::Tensor'. But testing using `auto myints = torch::zeros({7});` works flawlessly

Answer (score 3):

#### Pytorch 1.5 using `Tensor::index` and `Tensor::index_put_`

```
using namespace torch::indexing;

auto myints = torch::Tensor({10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70});
auto myvector = torch::ones({18});    
myvector.index_put_({3, 7}, myints.index({0, 3}));
```

[**General translation for `Tensor::index` and `Tensor::index_put_`**](https://pytorch.org/cppdocs/notes/tensor_indexing.html#setter)

```
Python             C++ (assuming `using namespace torch::indexing`)
-------------------------------------------------------------------
0                  0
None               None
...                "..." or Ellipsis
:                  Slice()
start:stop:step    Slice(start, stop, step)
True / False       true / false
[[1, 2]]           torch::tensor({{1, 2}})
```

#### Pytorch 1.4 alternative functions

```
Tensor Tensor::narrow(int64_t dim, int64_t start, int64_t length) 

Tensor & Tensor::copy_(const Tensor & src, bool non_blocking=false)
```

`narrow` is almost exactly like `slice` and using `copy_` for assignment

```
auto myints = torch::Tensor({10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70});
auto myvector = torch::ones({18});

myvector.narrow(0, 3, 4).copy_(myvector.narrow(0, 0, 3));
```