# Creating BoolTensor Mask in torch C++

Tags: c++, libtorch

I am trying to create a mask for torch in C++ of type `BoolTensor`. The first `n` elements in dimension `one` need to be `False` and the rest need to be `True`.

This is my attempt but I do not know if this is correct (size is the number of elements):

```
src_mask = torch::BoolTensor({6, 1});
src_mask[:size,:] = 0;
src_mask[size:,:] = 1;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure to understand exactly your goal here, so here is my best attempt to convert into C++ you pseudo-code .

First, with libtorch you declare the type of your tensor through the `torch::TensorOptions` struct (types names are prefixed with a lowercase k)

Second, your python-like slicing is possible thanks to the `torch::Tensor::slice`function (see [here](https://pytorch.org/cppdocs/notes/tensor_indexing.html) and [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56908893/copy-a-chunk-of-one-tensor-into-another-one-in-c-api/57737809#57737809)).

Finally, that gives you something like :

```
// Creates a tensor of boolean, initially all ones
auto options = torch::TensorOptions().dtype(torch::kBool));
torch::Tensor bool_tensor = torch::ones({6,1}, options);
// Set the slice to 0
int size = 3;
bool_tensor.slice(/*dim=*/0, /*start=*/0, /*end=*/size) = 0;

std::cout << bool_tensor << std::endl;
```

Please not that this will set the first `size` rows to 0. I assumed that's what you meant by "first elements in dimension x".

Comment: can you put the answer as accepted then, please ? :)

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it:

```
using namespace torch::indexing; //for using Slice(...) function

at::Tensor src_mask = at::empty({ 6, 1 }, at::kBool); //empty bool tensor 
src_mask.index_put_({ Slice(None, size), Slice() }, 0); //src_mask[:size,:] = 0
src_mask.index_put_({ Slice(size, None), Slice() }, 1); //src_mask[size:,:] = 0
```